# How can I split a string value and insert it in a different column in the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have column like this (all in varchar)

```
SIGN ON SIGN OFF              SIGN IN      SIGN OFF
-----------------------       --------   -----------
01-05-2015 / 20-04-2016         NULL        NULL
```

AND i want to do this:

```
SIGN ON SIGN OFF              SIGN IN      SIGN OFF
 -----------------------      --------     -----------
01-05-2015 / 20-04-2016       01-05-2015   20-04-2016
```

i try with string split from sql 2016 but he had on another line the values not the same.

how can i do it?

Comment: All caps is equivalent to shouting. It's also harder tor read

Comment: First, with such a simple format you could simply extract the first and last 10 characters. Second, you need to parse those strings and store them as proper dates if you want to be able to sort, search or use those values.

Comment: There are probably tens of duplicates for this question. Please search before asking.

Comment: `01-05-2015` comes *after* 02-01-1800` if the value is stored as `varchar(10)` or any other string type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i searched but the results are the string split to add to a new row.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its my problem here. this is a database imported from acess where the dates are varchar(max) with date / date. the data is not consistent because some are date /date.

Comment: Well then you should improve your search skills. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+split+string+to+columns) alone have almost 600 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string functions:

```
select col1,
       left(col1, charindex('/', col1) - 1),
       stuff(col1, 1, charindex('/', col1) + 1, '')
from t;
```

Comment: thanks manually is working. using the values from the table no. i had sucess using C# by split the date and create a new one and update dable on the new column. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=988c820f8231e1a73b0878761adc3a59)

```
  select 
      left(colname,charindex('/',colname)-1) as signon, 
      right(colname,charindex('/',colname)-1) as signoff
  from tablename
```

OUTPUT:

```
signon       signoff
01-05-2015   20-04-2016
```

Comment: thanks manually is working. using the values from the table no. i had sucess using C# by split the date and create a new one and update dable on the new column. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
select substring([SIGN ON SIGN OFF],1,charindex('/',[SIGN ON SIGN OFF])-2) as sign_in, 
substring([SIGN ON SIGN OFF],charindex('/',[SIGN ON SIGN OFF])+1,len([SIGN ON SIGN OFF])) as sign_off
```

Comment: thanks manually is working. using the values from the table no. i had sucess using C# by split the date and create a new one and update dable on the new column. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if i enter manually both answers worked. but for some reason executing was give me an error. so i give up from trying in the Sql code i did in c#.

here my solution that worked fo all cells.

```
 DBHelper.DBHelper da = new DBHelper.DBHelper();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = da.getAllEmbarques();


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                try
                {
                    List<SqlParameter> p = new List<SqlParameter>();
                    string nospaces = row[5].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                    string[] newsplit = nospaces.Split('/');
                    if (newsplit.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        string[] newsplit1 = newsplit[0].ToString().Split('-');

                        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(newsplit1[0]), Int32.Parse(newsplit1[1]), Int32.Parse(newsplit1[2]));
                        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@SIGNIN",SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        parameter.IsNullable = true;
                        parameter.Value = dt1;
                        p.Add(parameter);
                        parameter = new SqlParameter("@SIGNOFF", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        parameter.IsNullable = true;
                        parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
                        p.Add(parameter);                     
                        p.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", row[7].ToString()));


                        da.UpdateStringsplitEmbarques(p.ToArray());
                    }
                    else
                    if (newsplit.Count() == 2)
                    {
                        string[] newsplit1 = newsplit[0].ToString().Split('-');
                        string[] newsplit2 = newsplit[1].ToString().Split('-');

                        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(newsplit1[0]), Int32.Parse(newsplit1[1]), Int32.Parse(newsplit1[2]));
                        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(newsplit2[0]), Int32.Parse(newsplit2[1]), Int32.Parse(newsplit2[2]));
                        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@SIGNIN", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        parameter.IsNullable = true;
                        parameter.Value = dt1;
                        p.Add(parameter);
                        parameter = new SqlParameter("@SIGNOFF", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        parameter.IsNullable = true;
                        parameter.Value = dt2;
                        p.Add(parameter);
                        p.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", row[7].ToString()));
                        da.UpdateStringsplitEmbarques(p.ToArray());
                    }




                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
```

thanks you all for the time spending answering my question.

best regards